# How to add theme to magento?

Tags: magento

I have downloaded a theme in my system. I need to install this theme in magento.

How to do it?

I have installed theme using magento connect but how to do it for system saved in local files?

Answer (score 1):

If you have zip file , You can extract the downloaded theme into this location

```
"magento\app\design\frontend\default\yourtheme"
```

If you used the Magento Extension Login as admin

```
System --> Magento Connect --> Magento Connect Manager 
Given the Login Details
```

For Example : Hellowired theme 
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/HelloWired_Free_Theme_1_4

[image]

After Installation Your can see the source code (downloaded/installed) available in your local system

To enable your theme in FrontEnd

```
System --> Manage stores -->Create Store view -->  code (yourtheme)
```

May be it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a tutorial how to install magento template from local file, but this is tutorial with their template. But you can read and learn how do they do it.

http://www.magenmarket.com/news-and-blog/ma2-juno-free-magento-theme-installation-and-configuration.html

and there is detail about installing magento template via magento connect

http://www.magenmarket.com/news-and-blog/how-to-install-magento-themes-using-the-magento-connect-manager.html